# Way to refresh an item list after adding/removing an item with React/redux

Tags: reactjs, list, redux

I have a component `<ItemPage />` rendering a list of items and a form to add an item.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ItemsList />
            <AddItemForm />
        </div>
    )
}
```

My `<ItemsList />` has got a `componentDidMount()` method that calls the redux props function `this.props.items()` to list the items when the component is mounted.

When an item is added using `<AddItemForm />` component, the item is added to the database with an API POST request.

```
return dispatch => {
    axios(options)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: ITEM_ADDED,
                payload: response.data
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return dispatch(handleError(error))
        });
}
```

How am I supposed to refresh the list :

1. should I make an API GET request to get the updated item list ?
2. should I use the `response.data` which is supposed to send the item object that has just been created ?

Thank you for your help.

// ==================== EDITS ====================

If I choose the first option, the following code works:

```
return dispatch => {
  axios(postOptions)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: ITEM_ADDED,
        payload: response.data
      });
      // getItems(); // <= unfortunately, this doesn't work.
      axios(getOptions)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: ITEMS_FETCHED,
          payload: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return dispatch(handleError(error))
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return dispatch(handleError(error))
    });
}
```

There is ugly code repetitions, knowing I already have a fetch items function:

```
export function getItems() {
  ...
  return dispatch => {
    console.log('I am here') // <= when getItems() is inside addItem() function, 'I am here' is never displayed.
    axios(options)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: ITEMS_FETCHED,
          payload: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return dispatch(handleError(error))
      });
  }
}
```

How can I fix this please ?

And how to follow the "a function should do only one thing" principle ?

Comment: ```dispatch(getItems())``` is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63910796/making-clean-double-successive-axios-requests-with-react-redux) not to repeat the code.

Answer (score 0):

I’d recommend making a GET request after a successful POST request. This ensures that you’re getting the most up to date items objects from your API.

If you want to save yourself a GET you can take the response from your POST and append it to your items reducer state value. There isn’t really a downside to this I just always prefer to use the GET since you’ve already declared an action for it and unless your API is massive it shouldn’t lead to any extended or unnecessary loading times.

**EDIT**

The way you were currently using it, you won't hit `getItems` because it's async. Try putting the `getItems` in another `then`. See below.

```
return dispatch => {
  axios(postOptions)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: ITEM_ADDED,
        payload: response.data
      });  
    })
    .then(()=>getItems())
    .catch(error => {
      return dispatch(handleError(error))
    });
}
```

And in `getItems` replace `options` with `getOptions`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please have a look at my first post editings.

Comment: @Frankie Sorry for the late reply. I updated the answer.