# Making clean double successive axios requests with React/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I need to make an axios `post` request to update a list and then an axios `get` request to fetch the updated list.

I managed to do these operations with the following code `axios(postOptions)` then `axios(getOptions)`:

```
export function addItem() {
  ...
  return dispatch => {
    axios(postOptions)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: ITEM_ADDED,
          payload: response.data
        });
        // getItems(); // <= unfortunately, this doesn't work, so I repeat some code
        axios(getOptions)
          .then(response => {
            dispatch({
              type: ITEMS_FETCHED,
              payload: response.data
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
          return dispatch(handleError(error))
          });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return dispatch(handleError(error))
      });
}
```

The code works but I repeat myself as I already have this `getItems()` function:

```
export function getItems() {
  ...
  return dispatch => {
    console.log('I am here') // <= when getItems() is inside addItem() function, 'I am here' is never displayed.
    axios(options)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: ITEMS_FETCHED,
          payload: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return dispatch(handleError(error))
      });
  }
}
```

It could have been better to reuse this function but when the `getItems()` function is called inside the `addItem()` function, it never goes inside the `dispatch()`.

Can you help me to figure out what is going wrong please ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to call getItems inside dispatch like this dispatch(getItems())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getItems is a redux action, you need to call it in dispatch

```
dispatch(getItems())
```